# How to override the overlay css in jQuery-BlockUI

Tags: iphone, ios, css, jquery-blockui

I am using jquery BlockUI Plugin and I'm facing an issue.

In the iOS devices when in portrait mode the overlay comes fine but when the user switches to landscape mode the overlay comes but with the same resolution of the potrait mode which looks wierd.

So is there any way I can override the CSS of the overlay without editing anything in the jQuery BlockUI plugin or is there any setting that I need to do?

Comment: I'm having kind of the same issue but it only occures in landscape mode when I opened the keyboard. Did you found a a sollution for it? I think it might be a defect in jquery.blockui..

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that the page is being drawn at the larger width and when you are switching resolution to the portrait view the device it is not redrawing the page but resizing it. [Here is a jquery function](http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/jQuery_redraw-BGv) that may fix your problem.

Just call that function when you detect a window resize.